# How to extend existing constructor function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Let's suppose that I have the following object function:

```
function A(options){
 ...
}
```

Then I want to create a new function (B) that inherits A's prototype. 
These are the conditions I'm looking for:

- B's prototype, if modified, should not modify A's
- when calling to B function as a constructor, A's constructor should be called with the corresponding options.

B should look like this:

> function B(aOptions, bOptions){ ... }

```
var b = new B({}, {})
```

Comment: Javascript [doesn't have](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html) a classical inheritance mechanism.

Comment: Answers to many JS questions can be found on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Inheritance

Comment: There would be no need for 2 options. You can pass one and have the functions use or mutate whatever applies to that specific function. More on prototype and passing arguments to a chain of functions here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just call `A` constructor with `this`

```
function B(aOptions, bOptions) {
  A.call(this, aOptions);

  // do stuff with bOptions here...
}
```

Now to setup the prototype

```
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype, {
  constructor: {
    value: B
  }
});
```

Now B will have the prototype methods from A.

Any new methods added to B's prototype will **not** be available to A's prototype

---

There's a couple other tweaks that can make your life easier too.

```
function A(options) {

  // make `new` optional
  if (!(this instanceof A)) {
    return new A(options);
  }

  // do stuff with options here...
}
```

And do the same for B

```
function B(aOptions, bOptions) {

  // make `new` optional
  if (!(this instanceof B)) {
    return new B(aOptions, bOptions);
  }

  // call parent constructor
  A.call(this, aOptions);

  // do stuff with bOptions here...
}
```

Now you can call `A(options)` or `new A(options)` to get the same result.

Same with B, `B(aOptions, bOptions)` or `new B(aOptions, bOptions)` will get the same result.

Comment: so what will be the value of this in functon b ??..suppose if i call the function b with var a = new a() ..will that this point a or somewhat else ??

Comment: @AvinashBabu all of the code here makes no modifications to A. `new A()` calls `A`, not `B`. The value of `this` will point to an instance of `B` when you call `new B()`.

Comment: so if i call var b = new b() then the this points to the variable b right ??

Comment: @AvinashBabu `var b = new B()` will give you a new instance of B, yep.